# Trouble reading files in GAP

Tags: gap, computer-algebra-systems

I am trying to read a file in GAP. However, GAP believes the file does not exist. Using the IsExistingFile command, I have determined that GAP sees the parent folder, but not the .g file that I am trying to open. LastSystemError() tells me "No such file or directory".

I am running GAP 4.8.9 on Windows 7. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since this is just about the technical aspects of running the system and not about mathematics, feel free to send the question as-is to support@gap-system.org and I'll reply there.